# Mobs are not spawning in mob farm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

First of all, I am using mods, so that may be the cause.

I made a mob farm, without tutorial, and it doesnt work.

The ground height is at 32, the platform where the mobs are supposed to be spawning is at 57.
I placed water and trapdoors, checked multiple times, and it's completely dark.

I made a video to show surroundings and such (note that I had Cookie Clicker open):

Mods:

- [Phosphor](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/phosphor)
- [The Twilight Forest](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/the-twilight-forest)
- [Just Enough Items](https://github.com/mezz/JustEnoughItems)
- [Bookshelf](http://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/bookshelf)

The mods don't seem to have an effect on mob spawning, except maybe Phosphor, because that affects lighting.

Comment: Hi Bektop, welcome to Arqade, and thanks for a thorough first question! The mods you use indeed don't seem to have any effect on spawning. Did you go through [a list of related questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=minecraft+mobs+not+spawning) already?

Comment: Hey, i have taken a look at similar questions. I tried some solutions that worked for others but nothing worked. I also took a look at  common issues with "The Twilight Forest" mod, but nothing seems to be related to mob farming. I have also tried lowering the mob spawning area form 3 blocks high to 2, did not work.

Answer (score -1):

There might 2 possible reasons:

1. Not enough torches around the mob farm.
2. The mods are interfering with the game.(This happens if you run incompatible mods)

The Twilight Forest mod itself is a major mod. Maybe it is interfering with Phosphor mod(or vice-versa).